# Gazebo mimic joints property

Tags: ros, gazebo, joint, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm trying to "link" two joints with the mimic joint property. I readed that this property isn't suported officialy yet but there is in the code of Gazebo and can be used.

I readed here: http://www.ros.org/doc/api/urdf/html/joint_8h_source.html and found some exemples like this:

```
<joint name="r_gripper_r_finger_joint" type="revolute">
  <axis xyz="0 0 -1"/>
  <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.07691 -0.01 0"/>
  <limit effort="1000.0" lower="0.0" upper="0.548" velocity="0.5"/>
  <dynamics damping="0.2"/>
  <mimic joint="r_gripper_l_finger_joint" multiplier="1" offset="0"/>
  <parent link="r_gripper_palm_link"/>
  <child link="r_gripper_r_finger_link"/>
</joint>
```

But when I try to link my joints it has no efect, and when I apply one effort to a "joint_left_wheel" the "joint_right_wheel" (presumably connected) keeps in the position. My code is the next (I also tried with the next parameters ***joint_name*="joint_left_wheel" multiplier="1" offset="0"**), does you see any mistake?

```
<joint name="joint_right_wheel" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0.35 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0" />
  <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
  <mimic joint="joint_left_wheel" multiplier="1" offset="0"/>
  <parent link="chassis"/>
  <child link="right_wheel"/>
</joint>
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10249/gazebo-mimic-joints-property/) by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 197 on 2011-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately the tags are simply ignored in simulation at this point.  To do this right, a mimic constraint needs to be created in underlying physics engine (i.e. ODE) and propagated through gazebo to realize dynamics of mimicking.  Please [open a ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket) if this is a useful feature to you (note, you'll have to setup an account on [code.ros.org](https://code.ros.org) first before you can create tickets).

Thanks.

John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-06-15**:
all tickets defaults to me in simulator_gazebo, but I'll gladly accept patches or if anyone wants to pick it up :)  Thanks.

**Comment by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on 2011-06-14**:
Hi John, thanks for answer again. As you say, I created a ticket in code.ros.org, and I owned to you this ticket accidentally. If you wouldn't to work with this ticket, please change the owner. This is the ticket: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5005 Thanks!